# Virtual functions in dynamically linked C++ libs impossible?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, virtual-functions

As an example, this code segfaults (see comment in main.cpp).

**hello.h**

```
struct A { virtual ~A() {} };
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"

extern "C" {
    void hello(A*& a) {
        a = new A;
    }
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <cassert>
#include <dlfcn.h>

#include "hello.h"

int main() {

    void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    assert(handle);

    typedef void (*hello_t)(A*& a);
    hello_t hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, "hello");
    assert(hello);

    A* a = nullptr;
    hello(a);
    dlclose(handle);

    delete a; // -> segfault
}
```

**compile**

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g main.cpp -ldl -o main
g++ -Wall -std=c++11 -g -shared -fpic hello.cpp -o hello.so
```

The reason: `A` contains a virtual table. When `a` is being allocated, the virtual table contains pointers to the function segment of `hello.so`. After a call to `dlclose()`, this function segment may get invalid, causing the pointers to get invalid, and thus, the `delete a` calls functions which are out of memory.

So far so clear. My questions are, all assuming that you `dlclose()` your library and then continue using the objects:

1. Is it impossible to allocate objects of classes with virtual destructors in an .so file? Is there no better trick than implementing your own vtable on the heap?
2. If it is impossible, isn't it dangerous to allocate anything you don't know about in a shared library? Even if you know that `std::string` is guaranteed to be implemented without a virtual destructor, who knows if it holds an internal object with one?

Comment: Conceptually, you must not `dlclose()` until you use anything related to the shared library. Simple as that.

Comment: 1. no it is not impossible, I think you are doing it wrong: your lib calls new, but your app calls delete: start with moving the delete call into the lib as well; *edit* @TheParamagneticCroissant's comment makes a lot of sense as well

Comment: You're manually dyna-loading, then unloading your .so purposely before you destroy an object that references code in it. You *chose* to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: I've encountered a similar problem that doesn't involve calling dlclose().  It's on the Windows platform.  I have a third party omniORB DLL built with Visual Studio 2008.  My app is built with Visual Studio 2013.  At runtime, my app has a reference variable to an omniORB CORBA object created by omniORB DLL.  Memory corruption occurs when the omniORB CORBA object falls out of scope in my app.  The issue is that the omniORB CORBA object got allocated on the DLL's heap.  So when my app calls the omniORB CORBA object's destructor (compiler gen, it's trying to free the object using the app's heap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no problem with dynamically linked libraries.  They are not dangerous.

However, you are demonstrating the problem of unloading dynamically *loaded* libraries.  You can't unload a library and then continue to use references to data in that library: data pointers, function pointers, virtual functions, et cetera.  It is just like using a pointer after you `delete` it: the only answer is to avoid calling `delete` until you are done with the object.

So, using dynamically loaded libraries with `dlopen()` and `dlclose()` are as dangerous as `new` and `delete`... there is nothing to prevent you from doing the wrong thing, you have to know how to use these features correctly.

In typical usage (without dynamic loading), a dynamically linked library will remain resident for the entire duration of the program's execution.  So if `std::string` is in a dynamic library, its functions will always be available.  Just like a static library.

Comment: Thanks, but where is it stated that the heap of the loaded library will is not reliable after `dlclose()`? Is there anything in the `dlclose()` manpage that says it? I can only find this: "The only restriction on such a removal is that no object shall be  removed  to which references have been relocated, until or unless all such references are removed."

Comment: The problem here is not about heaps.  The problem is that you are calling a destructor, `A::~A()`, which is in a library which you unloaded.  Don't do that.  You must keep the library loaded if you want to use objects which that library contains, such as functions.

Comment: So you'd say that a function, if there's a "reference" (e.g. pointer, like the one on hello()) on it, does not vanish on `dlclose()`, however, this destructor here is not referenced by the main program and is thus not reliable to remain?

Comment: Why does the cite I showed two posts above say then that "no object shall be removed to which references have been relocated"? Did I get that wrong?

Comment: That is talking about references between libraries.  The `dlopen()` / `dlclose()` functions do not track references you create yourself, on the stack or the heap.

Comment: @LucDanton: It doesn't look that way to me.

Comment: @Johannes, when you `dlclose` a library, everything within it disappears.  All its data, all its code, everything.  It doesn't matter whether the rest of the program still has pointers to it.  When you close your library, the machine code that implements the `A::~A()` function is no longer in memory.

Comment: @LucDanton: The tag wikis appear to be inaccurate.  In general, they cannot always be relied upon.

Comment: @Wyzard Ok, so one probably must just assume that every code vanishes after `dlclose()`, since no one knows anything official stating anything about that. However, you guys agree that the heap is safe to remain?

Comment: @Johannes: It is official, because `dlclose()` unloads code: unloaded code vanishes.  It is in the man page.

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the destructor is virtual isn't really relevant here, because there's no inheritance involved.  The problem is simply that you're calling a function (the destructor) that's implemented in a library after you've closed that library.  A direct call to a non-virtual member function would cause the same problem, because the function's code is in the library and the library has been unloaded.

Just keep the library open until you're done using the objects it implements.

Comment: Thanks, but if I leave the virtual keyword, it works without any problems. Are you 100 percent sure that it has nothing to do with that?

Comment: It may happen to work in this case because the compiler probably inlines the trivial destructor so there's no actual function call occurring, but that's an implementation detail that you can't rely on.  It's undefined behavior, where "undefined" *sometimes* means "works without problems on this particular compiler, OS, phase of the moon, etc."

Comment: Why does the destructor `~A` get invalid if it is non virtual? It is known to the `main` binary, as it is declared in hello.h, isn't it?

Comment: Defining a function within the class body (as you've done with the destructor) is equivalent to declaring it `inline`.  But `inline` is just a *request* that the compiler is free to ignore.  It's entirely valid for the compiler to ignore the definition in the header and emit a normal function call.  (Though in that case, you'd actually get an "undefined reference" error when trying to link your `main` program; you wouldn't even be able to run it.)

Comment: It may be that the definition in the header is enough to ensure that the destructor's implementation is available in `main` regardless of whether it's inlined; I'm not sure whether that's portable or reliable, since the C++ standard doesn't specify details of how linking works.

Comment: Hmm.  Section 3.2 of the C++11 standard ("One definition rule") says "An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used."  If that means that `~A` is guaranteed to be defined in the `main.cpp` translation unit (regardless of whether it's actually inlined), then my answer is probably incorrect:  the `virtual` keyword is the only thing forcing a call to the definition in the library instead of in the `main` program.  (But this is implementation-specific:  the standard doesn't specify how virtual calls are implemented.)

Answer (score 5):

Your analysis is incorrect. The problem is not that the after `dlclose(handle)` the code for your destructor doesn't exist any longer, which means that your code crashes. Keep the library open, and the destructor can be called.

However, you do in some cases also get a different heap per shared library, so it's a good idea to keep the construction and destruction for dynamically allocated objects within the shared library. You could achieve this by a second function `bye()` that does `delete` of your object.

Typically the problem of "adding stuff dynamically" (your example with a `std::string` is not great, as the implementation should only ever allocate `char` elements, but `std::vector` would potentially allocate things when copying elements, for example) is handled by encapsulating it within the object, that way the allocations are done by the code that is in the shared library.

(There are details in your analysis that are wrong too: the vtable itself is not stored on the heap, but the vptr that points to it has to be stored within the object, and in this case, that is on the heap)

Comment: Thanks, but can you please find anything that states that the code for my destructor is not reliable anymore? Maybe from a manpage or so? See also my reply to Dietrich Epp. Also, where does it state that I can get a different heap per library?

Comment: @Johannes: WELCOME to the C++ HELL.  When you work with C++ ad DLLs you are mixing up different memory models from technologies (C++ and DLLs) that are each other ignorant (Their both trust C, but no more that that). So don't expect one documenting the other's fault or danger.  Different run-time modules use different data-segment, an that can go in different heaps by design. C++ assumes memory is contiguous and with unique addressing. The two things don't go in the same direction. It's up to you to drive them coherently

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Does this imply that allocating objects the way I did is bad, because you can never call their destructor?

Comment: @Johannes: It's only really a problem on Windows, if the library was compiled using a different runtime.  On Linux or OS X, there are generally no problems.

Comment: There can be the same problem, because it's related to the x86 architecture more than the OS. On linux normally you don't experience it because the run-time is part of the distribution (and hence more uniform).